# Splitting wireshark large size with pcap splitter with bash

Tags: bash, wireshark, pcap

I have large pcapng files, and I want to split them based on my desired wireshark filters. I want to split my files by the help of bash scripts and using [pcapsplitter](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/PcapSplitter), but when I use a loop, it always gives me the same file.

I have written a small code.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {57201..57206}
do
mkdir destination/$i
done

tcp="tcp port "

for i in {57201..57206}
do
tcp="$tcp$i"
pcapsplitter -f file.pcapng -o destination/$i -m bpf-filter -p $tcp
done
```

the question is, can I use bash for my goal or not? 
If yes, why it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, this is something Bash can do.

Regarding your script, the first thing I can think of is this line :

```
pcapsplitter -f file.pcapng -o destination/$i -m bpf-filter -p $tcp
```

where the value of `$tcp` is actually `tcp port 57201` (and following numbers on the next rounds. However, without quotes, you're actually passing `tcp` only to the `-p` parameter.

It should work better after you've changed this line into :

```
pcapsplitter -f file.pcapng -o destination/$i -m bpf-filter -p "$tcp"
```

NB: as a general advice, it's usually safer to double-quote variables in Bash.

NB2 : you don't need those 2 `for` loops. Here is how I'd rewrite your script :

```
#!/bin/bash

for portNumber in {57201..57206}; do
    destinationDirectory="destination/$portNumber"
    mkdir "$destinationDirectory"

    thePparameter="tcp port $portNumber"
    pcapsplitter -f 'file.pcapng' -o "$destinationDirectory" -m bpf-filter -p "$thePparameter"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it saves my time a lot. the fact of using ` " " ` really helped me. I've also corrected my stupid way of using 2 for loops ;) . if someone else read this comment, i also suggest to delete extra files with `rm` command and rename the desired file with `mv` . in this way it would be easier to use those files.